# Undefined variable when passing data from a Model to a View via Controller in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, controller, laravel-blade

I am getting an undefined variable error when passing more than three instances of data from models to a view via a controller in Laravel. I have followed the same procedure as before for my previous  cases (have another 2 models that are passing through okay and work as expected).

Files below

**Controller.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Models\tickets;
use App\Models\ticketcategory;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\nihejobnumber;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class TicketMe extends Controller
{
    public function createTicket()
    {
        return view('createticket', 
            ['ticketcategory' => ticketcategory::where('isactive', 1)->get()], 
            ['users' => User::where('status', 1)->get()], 
            ['nihejobs' => nihejobnumber::all()]);
    }
}
```

Getting the error with the 'nihejobs' variable being undefined within a foreach in my view

**createticket.blade.php**

```
<div id="modalNiheJobNumberBody">
    @foreach ($nihejobs as $nihejobnumber)
        <div  @class([
                                    'user-lookup-div' => $loop->odd,
                                    'user-lookup-div2' => $loop->even
                                    ]) onclick="addNiheJobNumber('{{ $users->userid }}')">
            <jobnumber style="padding-left: 5pt;">{{ $nihejobnumber->internaljobnumber }}<jobnumber>
                    <address style="padding-left: 5pt;">{{ $nihejobnumber->address }}</address>

        </div>
```

Can someone please give some advice where I am going wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact error message? I can see `$users->userid` giving an error about unable to get the property on the collection since `$users` is a collection of users and not a single model instance.

Comment: @aynber even without this onclick data it still errors. Getting error:
Undefined variable $nihejobs when accessing the view.

I've passed other models' data for the same view and it worked fine, just not working with nihejobs

Comment: You're passing 3 arrays to `view('createticket, [], [], [])`, but the syntax is `view('name', [])`; you need to use a single array: `return view('createticket', ['ticketcategory' => ticketcategory::where('isactive', 1)->get(), 'users' => User::where('status', 1)->get(), 'nihejobs' => nihejobnumber::all()]);`

Comment: @TimLewis Thanks for getting back to me, yep that has worked. Apologies still learning and wasn't sure I could pass as one array.

Comment: No problem! If you need them separated into 3 arrays, you can do `->view('name')->with([])->with([])->with([])`, but having them as a single associative array is generally preferred/cleaner. Cheers! 